# Union type as key in interface?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use a union type as a key in an interface? For example, I want to do something like this:

```
interface IMargin {
  [key in 'foo' | 'bar']: boolean;
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)

Is there any way around this?

The use case is turning an array of values into an interface:

```
const possibleTypes = ['foo', 'bar'];
interface Types {
    foo?: boolean;
    bar?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `keyof Types`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interfaces do not support mapped types (which is what you are looing for here). You can use a type alias, for most uses it should work the same (not all cases but if the types are known you can implement the type alias just as you would the interface).

```
const possibleTypes = (<T extends string[]>(...o: T) => o)('foo', 'bar');
type Types = Record<typeof possibleTypes[number], boolean>
```

The mapped type `Record` should work will here

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. That works fine, as long as you pass in `('foo', 'bar')` directly. However, it doesn't work when you pass in `(...['foo', 'bar'])`. Is there any way to fix this? The use case here is generating a type or interface from an array.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville you mean to the IIFE in `possibleTypes`?  The idea is that the array should be of a literal type that is either typed as the tuple `['foo', 'bar']` or the array `Array<'foo' | 'bar'>`. If you have that array correctly typed you can just use that without the IIFE. Otherwise you either need to type assert it to something that is of one of the types above. If it's just a syntactic preference to use an array you can go with `const possibleTypes = (<T extends string>(o: T[]) => o)(['foo', 'bar']);` but I like the original version better :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville the `(...['foo', 'bar'])`  does not work, this a limitation of ts. The array literal will be inferred to `string[]` before the spread operation and thus the literal types are lost

Comment: Ah, I see. That helps more, and we're getting there! I'm still getting stuck though pulling this into my actual use case. I have a feeling the string literal type is getting lost in translation somewhere. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dftj9c

Comment: @ElliotBonneville that is a horse of a different color .. you can't create string literal types from concatenations unfortunately. Your types are getting lost anyway because the parameters are types as `string[]` which can be solved with generics. But you still could not generate `prefix1_a` as a string literal type in the type system currently.

Comment: Wait, I've got it, I think. Just had to cast to `T`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dftj9c

Comment: Nope, close. It's not including the concatenated strings.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville trust me it's not possible to get it to work with concatenations. This is a current limitation of TS. If you want we can get it to work without those properties .. btu that is about it ..

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it's straight up ignoring them. What about using Symbols or something of that nature? Is there absolutely no way to achieve this? Doesn't have to be string literals -- just some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville If you are wiling to change you design, putting them in nested objects within the interface I think would be the most effective way to do it ..

Comment: Ah, I see. The type or interface is used as props validation for a React component, actually, so I don't think that would work -- the structure would need to be flat I guess.

Answer (score 57):

You can use an object type instead of an interface, which are mostly interchangeable:

```
type IMargin = {
    [key in 'foo' | 'bar']: boolean;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks -- adopting type instead of interface gets me part of the way there. As you can see in my comment on Titian's answer, though, I'm still stuck generating the union type from the array.

Comment: I get `A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)`

Answer (score 18):

This is not necessarily an answer, but I think this may interest others.

You can use a Union Type **as a key in a sub-property** of an Interface.

```
export type Language = 'EN' | 'DE' | 'IT';

export interface Document {
  generic: string;
  languages: {
    [key in Language]: string[];
  }
}
```

Comment: It's treated like using the `type` keyword. If you used `type` instead of `interface` you'd be permitted to do it there too.

Comment: but what in case, I don't want to specify all languages? With that, right now, all languages are required. How to ensure that key simply belongs to specified keys, without requiring them all?

Comment: Hello @noisy, i know its an old comment, but did you get a workaround to get just one of the languages as a single key, instead of multiple possible keys ?

Comment: @HéctorLeón -- I [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77822738/2084315) to address your question, does that help? (Basically wrap it with a `Partial<T>`

Answer (score 2):

convert possible types to enum
convert interface to type since An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead

```js
enum possibleTypes { 'foo', 'bar' };
type Types {
    [key in keyof typeof possibleTypes]: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const possibleTypes = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type Types = Record<typeof possibleTypes[number], boolean>
```

Saying `as const` we declare that the array is immutable and not just `Array<string>`.
`possibleTypes[number]` is needed to filter out array methods, like `length` from the type.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on the other answers, and adds an answer to a question about selectively specifying languages.

I prefer the use of `Record` over the index specification (`[key of/in]`) as it's a bit easier to read and understand (`Record<property name type, value type>`).

The additional question:

> did you get a workaround to get just one of the languages as a single key, instead of multiple possible keys?

In this case, use the [`Partial` helper](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype). Wrapping anything with `Partial<other type>` makes all the properties optional (able to be undefined).

[Here's a playground example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

```
export type Language = 'EN' | 'DE' | 'IT';

export type LanguageMap = Partial<Record<Language, string[]>>;

export class Document {
    public generic: string;
    public languages: LanguageMap;

    constructor(generic: string, langMap: LanguageMap) {
        this.generic = generic;
        this.languages = langMap;
    }
}

const x = new Document(
    'test',
    {
        'EN': ['English', 'British English', 'Australian English', 'US English']
    }
);

const y = new Document(
    'test',
    // this can be empty!
    {
    }
);
```